# Gulp is stuck on "start watch"

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

The "watch" function does not work. After I run "gulp watching" command, make changes in my "style.scss" file, save it and wait for changes, but nothing happens. All I get is "Starting "watching""... All paths are correct. [screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVYEW.png)

```
const { src, dest, watch } = require("gulp");

const scss = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));

const concat = require("gulp-concat");

function styles() {
  return src(path.source.scss)
    .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: "expanded" }))
    .pipe(dest(path.source.css))
    .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: "compressed" }))
    .pipe(concat("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(dest(path.build.css));
}

function watching() {
  watch(path.watch.scss, styles);
}

exports.styles = styles;
exports.watching = watching;
```

Gulp version: 4.0.2